# What is the Prospect's highest m^3 mining rate?

Tags: eve-online

Assuming perfect skills, no fleet boosts and no implants, what's the highest rate in m^3 per hour of ore that the prospect can mine?

Comment: Not enough to make ninja mining worth while if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Well, yes, but I'm going to do it for "fun" so there's worthiness in that alone.

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter what it's theoretical highest mining rate is. Just slap on the best modules you're willing to lose and go have fun.

Comment: Well... yes and no to whether or not it "doesn't matter". I'm accumulating a series of high-risk low-cost activities for fun and this is one of those. I would like to know where prospect ninja mining stands in relation to other activities in terms of isk potential, and it's a useful question for other people to know the answer to also.

Comment: The problem is that theoretical best fitting is will probably wouldn't have a cloaking module, and maybe a rare and very expensive module or two. It wouldn't be representative of practical ninja mining in terms of risk and reward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given max skills, 759m3/minute (45,540m3/hour):

```
[Prospect, max yield]
Mining Laser Upgrade II
Mining Laser Upgrade II
Mining Laser Upgrade II
Internal Force Field Array I

Limited 1MN Microwarpdrive I
Scoped Survey Scanner
Medium Shield Extender II

Miner II
Miner II
Covert Ops Cloaking Device II

Small Processor Overclocking Unit II
Small Core Defense Field Extender I
```

The fit is *very* tight and requires a 3% CPU implant for it all to fit. You can only fit two Miner IIs because it only has 2 turret slots, so the covert cloak is the obvious choice.

Edit: Modified based on comments. Will fit without a CPU implant and has a better yield (861m3/minute):

```
[Prospect, max yield]
Mining Laser Upgrade II
Mining Laser Upgrade II
Erin Mining Laser Upgrade
Internal Force Field Array I

Limited 1MN Microwarpdrive I
Scoped Survey Scanner
Medium Shield Extender II

Modulated Deep Core Miner II, Veldspar Mining Crystal II
Modulated Deep Core Miner II, Veldspar Mining Crystal II
Covert Ops Cloaking Device II

Small Processor Overclocking Unit II
Small Core Defense Field Extender I
```

You do need really good fitting skills, though. For under 40m ISK, you can't really go wrong and there's no real reason for faction/deadspace.

Comment: One of the requirements was no implants. Also Modulated Deep Core Miner IIs loaded with tech 2 crystals have a bigger yield than Miner IIs.

Comment: @RossRidge You're right, edited. Been a while since I've used the modulated miners and they were in a different place in EFT. :)